# How does react differentiate similar keys for two arrays with same parent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In Dan Abramov blog post, I read

> Note that the key is only relevant **within a particular parent React**
> element, such as a form. React won’t try to “match up” elements with
> the same keys between different parents.

So it says here:

```
let data = [0, 1];
return (
  <div>
    <div>
      {data.map((x) => (
        <span key={x}>{x}</span>
      ))}
    </div>
    <div>
      {data.map((x) => (
        <span key={x}>{x}</span> // has different parent but same keys
      ))}{" "}
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

React won't confuse the span elements **even though they have same keys, because they belong to different parents**.

But how would React differentiate, for example, such case?

```
let data = [0, 1];

return (
  <div>
    <span key={0}>0</span>
    {data.map((x) => (
      <span key={x}>{x}</span>
    ))}
    {data.map((x) => (
      <span key={x}>{x}</span>
    ))}
  </div>
);
```

Would reconciliation work correctly in this case? How?

Because above thing would translate to something like:

```
<div>
  <span key="0">0</span>
  <span key="0">0</span>
  <span key="1">1</span>
  <span key="0">0</span>
  <span key="1">1</span>
</div>
```

But I don't get any warning with above code, so seems React is able to do Reconciliation correctly still.

Comment: I lack a proper understanding of how exactly this works, but `key` is not really an attribute on the actual DOM. I reckon you are perfectly aware of this, but I guess this is still the key (no pun intended) here. React internally deals with two arrays of elements, so there is some form of scope.

Comment: @hotpink yes I just put it on DOM to illustrate my point. Yeah probably there is some form of scope you are right, I also manually added one span in example before arrays. But yeah to answer this one must know exactly how this reconciliation works.

Comment: quick solution - add to one of the map `key={'key2${x}'}`, and use this (`) instead of this(')

Comment: `map` returns an array, not individual `span` elements, so both `map` aren't merged and thus doesn't share the same parent. They each have their own parent, which is equivalent to a `Fragment`.

Answer (score 1):

I have no definitive proof but I don't think this case is missing a warning. I rather suppose React does something like [`React.Children.toArray`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildrentoarray) when encountering an array of children:

> React.Children.toArray() changes keys to preserve the semantics of nested arrays when flattening lists of children. That is, toArray prefixes each key in the returned array so that each element’s key is scoped to the input array containing it.

So my guess would be that reconciliation works here.

Additionally, I personally would implement an "duplicate key" check in a late rendering stage, so that all edge cases (including your example) are catched. There's no warning, so that's IMO a strong clue that there are no duplicate keys.

Answer (score -2):

It should warn you, it only warns if a key is not present, but if you start manipulating the states of those elements you might run into issues.